# unrecognized token: "\" in sqlite

Tags: php, sqlite

i was running my codes and i received this error

[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]
  An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE
                  ImportGenius\Entities\SQLite\TradeBase\UnitedStates\UnitedStatesImporterIndex RENAME TO ImportGenius\Entities\SQLite\TradeBa
  se\UnitedStates\UnitedStatesImporterIndexTemp_2,
                  ImportGenius\Entities\SQLite\TradeBase\UnitedStates\UnitedStatesImporterIndexTemp RENAME TO ImportGenius\Entities\SQLite\Tra
  deBase\UnitedStates\UnitedStatesImporterIndex
                  ':
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 unrecognized token: "\"

This is my codes:

```
private function switchTable(Connection $connection, $primaryTableName, $tempTableName)
{
    $secondaryTempTableName = $tempTableName.'_2';
    $rawSqlQuery = "ALTER TABLE 
            {$primaryTableName} RENAME TO {$secondaryTempTableName},
            {$tempTableName} RENAME TO {$primaryTableName}
            ";

    $stmt = $connection->prepare($rawSqlQuery);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: You need to provide the values of your variables.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely one of those four variables in your SQL statement actually has a `\` character in it, or is otherwise malformed.

92.7% <sup>(a)</sup> of all SQL statement problems can be solved if you just *print out your query* before trying to execute it, something like:

```
var_dump ($rawSqlQuery);
```

In this case, `\` is not a valid character for a table name. In fact, it's not a valid stand-alone token at all.

If you examine the SQLite source code responsible for handling various table names (`sqlite3CreateTable`, `sqlite3AlterRenameTable` and so on), they generally boil down to calling `sqlite3GetToken` to get the table names.

That function, in turn, does a large amount of checking of the token characters but the bottom line is that, outside a string, `\` returns the token `TK_ILLEGAL` - it doesn't match any valid tokens so it simply falls out of the `switch` statement at which point you see:

```
*tokenType = TK_ILLEGAL;
return 1;
```

This means that it's not valid in that context.

And, in fact, you can see that if you enter any of the following "commands":

```
\;
create table x\y (a integer);
alter table x rename to a\b;
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Statistic plucked from thin air, actual value may vary :-)

Comment: yes it has and the "\" should be there cause it is a link